# How to determine max amps over a common ground between AC-to-DC Adapters?

Tags: current, ac, raspberry-pi, ground, ws2811

How can I determine the expected and max current running over a common ground wire between DC of AC/DC converters? Should I fuse the wire?

I have two 5V/40A AC-to-DC adapters (AC is 3-pin each) for x-mas lights (WS2811) and 1 5V/1A adapter (AC is 2-pin) for raspberry pi. My aim is to have the raspberry pi acts as a controller and have the layout look something like this:
[image]
with the following differences:

- The Raspberry Pi will take the place of the controller and be powered by a USB 5V/1A via the microUSB port on the device
- They are 5V supplies

I was planning on going directly from a DC ground on a 5V/40V to a ground pin on the Raspberry Pi, powering the Pi via the normal microUSB interface, and connecting the two 5V/40A grounds like the above diagram.
[image]

The main thing I am currently concerned about it how many amps can flow over the common ground and if I am going to burn out the Pi or melt wire that is too small.

Comment: Do you know what kind of AC-to-DC adapters they are? That is, do you know what circuit is inside them?

Comment: DO NOT fuse ground or neutral, that's the last place you want to break a misoperating circuit, any protection goes on the mains "hot" or DC positive rails.  You will of course need *isolated* power supplies.  Connect the common ground between the pi and the LED strip at exactly and only the point and wire routing where you feed *data* from the pi to the strip, as the only purpose of that ground is to be a reference/return for the data currents.

Comment: @user253751 the raspberry pi is powered on a normal USB phone charger and the 5V/40A supplies are:  :https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07TSKK4FR/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: @ChrisStratton thank you for clarifying that the ground is just a reference for modulation and not tied to the rest of the Pi's power, was not clear.

Comment: To be clear, each system needs the ground to its own power supply for power currents, it's the *common ground between* that carries only the signal reference/return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the common ground connection *should* be only acting as a reference equalization for the control signal, there should be very little current (a few mA) running through it.  If you are concerned, hook up an ammeter and verify it as you add boards.  I'd be more concerned about trying to run 40A through the traces of the first board connected to the power supply.

Comment: The 5V/40A give power to the lights in 3-6 V parallel branches and each branch is fused.

Comment: so you think an 18 or 22 awg would work?

Comment: I'm not sure what "3-6V parallel branches" means but looking at your circuit you have 12V power supplies shown but 5V power supplies listed.  The driver you reference has a constant current output of 18.5mA typical.  If you have 200 of them, you're drawing less than 4A.  Take a look at an ampacity chart to verify, but 18 AWG should have no problem with 4A.

Comment: I meant 3-6 Amp branches from the 5V supply, typo.